# Free source of historical ETF units outstanding data?

Tags: market-data, historical-data, etf

I am looking for a free source of historical daily data of the number of outstanding units of ETFs and ETNs.  On a Bloomberg, this would be "VXX.SO Index HP" or something like that.

Does anyone know of any?

Comment: Probably should be community wiki as this is a question with many possible answers

Answer (score 2):

Many funds, that manage ETFs provide this on their webpages. E.g. SDPR (SPY, XL* family) has is in "NAV history" xls file on https://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=SPY